# How do I stop this error on specific Orgs? What feature is Causing it?

Tags: chat, flash

I use Chrome and sometimes Firefox.
I get a Flash Plugin warning even though the plugin is not installed.

But only in some Orgs.

This is causing the Error.
I found the url: https://umps1-c1-phx.salesforce.com/umps/UMPSWidget_184/images/message_alert_new.swf
Which is an audio alert.

[image: Initial Error]

[image: Error Icon]

I screen shot the html (expanded) I found the chat feature causing it. I will keeping looking.
[image: html]

Comment: I think this is caused by the chatter chat component in classic (the little instant message like tab in the bottom right of the screen). I bet you can turn this off in settings but am not familiar with where.

Comment: You are right.
I think this is a whole of Org (on/off) selection, not per person.

Comment: Seemingly no way to turn off chat per person. Not 100%. maybe a JS widget???

Answer (score 2):

Each person has Chat Options within the Chat overlay.
there is a "Play Sounds Option"
I turned this off and the Error went away.
Obviously I wont get notifications, but because it is flash I am not getting them anyway.
Pointless feature when browsers do not support Flash.